# Guardando dados passados - Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, na minha aplicação eu tenho um modelo Perfil que possui os seguintes campos:

Models.py:

```
class Perfil(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pontuacao_total = models.FloatField(max_length=4, default=0)
    pontuacao_ultima = models.FloatField(max_length=4, default=0)
```

Nessa aplicação, vão ter várias rodadas de jogadas, nessa modelagem, cada rodada vai ter sua pontuação associada ao campo `pontuacao_ultima`, e a `pontuacao_total` será a soma dessas pontuações. 
Por exemplo:

1º Rodada: 10 pontos

2º Rodada: 15 pontos

Neste caso, `pontuacao_ultima` vai ser igual a 15 e `pontuacao_total` igual a 25.

Porém nesta forma de abordar a situação existe um problema grande que é a perda dos dados, só vou ter armazenado as pontuações totais e as últimas de cada jogador.

Então queria pedir uma sugestão para alguma solução neste caso, o que posso fazer para não perder estes dados? Pelo que pesquisei não existe a possibilidade de um campo do modelo ser uma lista que armazenaria o valor de cada rodada...

Alguém pode me dar uma luz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa criar um modelo para armazenar as Rodadas, algo como:

```
class Rodada(models.Model):
    jogador = models.ForeignKey(Perfil, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rodadas')
    rodada = models.IntegerFileld()
    pontos = models.FloatField(max_length=4, default=0)
```

Daí não precisa armazenar pontuações no perfil do usuário para acessar esta informação.

Depois crie dois métodos dentro da classe Perfil para recuperar a pontuação da rodada mais alta e outro para somar a pontuação de um determinado usuário.

```
class Perfil(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    @property
    def pontuacao_total(self)
        total = 0
        if hasattr(self,'rodadas'):
           for rodada in self.rodadas.all()
               total += rodada.pontos
        return total

    @property
    def pontuacao_ultima(self)
        ultima = 0
        if hasattr(self, 'rodadas'):
            ultima = self.rodadas.last().pontos
        return ultima
```

Comment: Ótima solução por sinal.